# Finder wants to connect to non available AFP Server

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, afp

I have a little FreeBSD machine with Netatalk as my fileserver. I connect to it via the Finder and for two days now I get this window every minute as long as the server is offline:

[image]

I can't find the cause of this annoying window. I'm not trying to connect to and I can't find out why the Finder wants to. I already turned off Time Machine but that didn't work.

Any ideas? I hope this is my fault and not some really annoying Lion bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the server, then disconnecting from it by clicking the eject button next to the drive in Finder.